# I have a function with many variables. How do I use them in another function?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, function, variables

```
var min = document.getElementById("minutes");
var sec = document.getElementById("second");
//sets a time interval to repeat. 
setInterval(() => { //function() is the same as () => {} or () =>
    let d = new Date(); //creating a variable to get the Time
    let h = d.getHours(); //creating a variable to get hours and so on..
    let m = d.getMinutes();
    let s = d.getSeconds();
    var Hours = 30*h+m/2+s/120;//calculating
    var Minutes = 6*m+s/10;
    var Seconds = 6*s;

    hou.style.transform = `rotate(${Hours}deg)`;
    min.style.transform = `rotate(${Minutes}deg)`;
    sec.style.transform = `rotate(${Seconds}deg)`;
},1000)

function setAlarm(){
    let h = document.getElementById("h");
    let m = document.getElementById("m");
    let s = document.getElementById("s");
    if (h.innerHTML==Hours){
        console.log(true);
    }
}
```

I want to print true in my console if the value of the variable **h** in **setAlarm()** function is equal to the **Hours** variable in **setInterval()**.
How do I do that?

Comment: Well for one, `h` in `setAlarm()` is an HTMLElement, not a number. You likely want the `.innerHTML` of that element. `Hours` is just a calculation using the current date. You could perform the same calculation in the same manner inside your `setAlarm()` function. Also `h=Hours` is an assignment, not a comparison. You want `==`.

Comment: what exactly is`hou`. It would be easier to understand your problem clearly if you could add HTML also...

Comment: I did the appropriate changes. Thanks for pointing out the mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not positive this is what your'e asking but I'm pretty sure all you need to do is move the variable declarations out of the function like.

```js
var min = document.getElementById("minutes");
var sec = document.getElementById("second");
let Hours;
//sets a time interval to repeat. 
setInterval(() => { //function() is the same as () => {} or () =>
    let d = new Date(); //creating a variable to get the Time
    let h = d.getHours(); //creating a variable to get hours and so on..
    let m = d.getMinutes();
    let s = d.getSeconds();
    Hours = 30*h+m/2+s/120;//calculating
    var Minutes = 6*m+s/10;
    var Seconds = 6*s;

    hou.style.transform = `rotate(${Hours}deg)`;
    min.style.transform = `rotate(${Minutes}deg)`;
    sec.style.transform = `rotate(${Seconds}deg)`;
},1000)

function setAlarm(){
    let h = document.getElementById("h");
    let m = document.getElementById("m");
    let s = document.getElementById("s");
    if (h=Hours){
        console.log(true);
    }
}
```

### Edit

As stated in the comments there are some issues with the code, here is my advice to you. Don't use duplicate identifier names in different functions as it will probably confuse you as a begginer. Move all variable names that need accessed from multiple functions to the global scope.

Comment: the conditon (h=Hours) will never come true, because h is a html element, and House is a number

Comment: And you are assigning `Hours` to `h` **not** comparing them.

Comment: np, keep at it. Everything will make sense eventually!

Answer (score 0):

Just nope, but you can either expose the variable to upper scope or just invoke the setAlarm function in setInterval.

```js
var min = document.getElementById("minutes");
var sec = document.getElementById("second");
//sets a time interval to repeat. 
setInterval(() => { //function() is the same as () => {} or () =>
    let d = new Date(); //creating a variable to get the Time
    let h = d.getHours(); //creating a variable to get hours and so on..
    let m = d.getMinutes();
    let s = d.getSeconds();
    var Hours = 30*h+m/2+s/120;//calculating
    var Minutes = 6*m+s/10;
    var Seconds = 6*s;

    hou.style.transform = `rotate(${Hours}deg)`;
    min.style.transform = `rotate(${Minutes}deg)`;
    sec.style.transform = `rotate(${Seconds}deg)`;
    setAlarm(Hours);
},1000)

function setAlarm(Hours){
    let h = document.getElementById("h");
    let m = document.getElementById("m");
    let s = document.getElementById("s");
    if (h == Hours){
        console.log(true);
    }
}
```